# Why do wizards like Martin keep transporting back to the exact moment in the future from whence they came in Off to be the Wizard?

Tags: plot-device, off-to-be-the-wizard

In *Off to be the Wizard* the characters like Martin keep returning to the same point in time from where they traveled back to Medieval England when they need something from the future.

In Martin's case (and based on comments from Phillip, in the case of many "wizards"), this is incredibly dangerous due to being sought by the federal police. The FBI and Treasury agents are actively raiding Martin's parents' home, but he keeps going back there and risks having his phone taken, being beaten, and getting arrested.

Given that they can travel to any point in the past, if they want pizza, or to use the bathroom, or to buy a new computer, etc, why don't they just travel to 10 years in the past (1992 in Martin's case) or something like that?

Even if they were worried about picking good coordinates, someone like Martin (from 2012) could use the home of another wizard like Phillip, Jimmy, etc who is from the 80's or 90's. I don't get why he's tempting fate.

Comment: Thanks @Valorum . And by the way this is one piece of fiction I totally totally recommend unlike the movie you watched recently based on a question by me ;)

Comment: does the book go into any details about 'paradoxes'? Where time travel is involved, it's generally a good idea to mess as little as possible with your own timeline -- travelling into your own recent past could be disastrous if you accidentally changed something relevant to your life.

Comment: @KutuluMike it goes into it a lot but takes a different approach to keep things fun and light hearted, which is basically that no change to the past affects the future. They don't know why this is. They have a couple of different theories. But they tested it. For instance they change the name of London to Camelot and introduced magic and advances from the future to the past,  but it didn't make any difference. At least in the part of the book I'm at.

Comment: When it comes down to it, Martin just isn't all that smart.  (Although if I remember rightly he does *eventually* work this out.)  I don't know that using another wizard's home would be a good idea, though, too much scope for something to go wrong and result in a causal loop - presumably this is also why they never time-traveled between different times in Medieval England.

Comment: (Out of universe, of course, unrestricted time-travel would have spoiled the plot lines too much.)

Comment: well most of the wizards have a "safehouse" in the real world were they take shits, Martin knows when the agents are coming if i remember right, so he isnt really worried about his 10 second hops to the present(his present)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Fair enough. I may be setting myself up for a spoiler here because I still have 3 hours left in the audiobook.

Comment: @KutuluMike time travel isn't invoked.  In this series, they are basically inside the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read it this way:

- They can travel to any time/location in the past.
- They can travel to only the point of their 'own' time from which they last departed.
- When they travel to their own time, the passage of time runs as normal.
- When they're in the past, the passage of time in their *own* time stops.

So if they travel back in time from 10:20 on monday, when they go back to their *own* time it is still 10:20. Say they spend 1/2 an hour there and travel back to the past, when they next travel back to their *own* time it will be 10:50 on monday.

As you point out, why not use the home of another wizard from the past or future? Well, if they travel to the home of a wizard from their past then they *might* meet the wizard there, that wizard will have information about the future which is likely to be dangerous. If they were to travel to the home of a wizard from the future, either the wizard doesn't yet exist or doesn't yet live there or, the wizard hasn't started travelling yet. If this is the case then the information that could be given could be dangerous.

Reading this back I'm aware that it is confusion but all questions/answers relating to time travel are. Furthermore, as Harry Johnston points out, Martin isn't that smart and He's confused about the mechanics of the universe so the author has made sure that we are as well !

Comment: `They can travel to only the point of their 'own' time from which they last departed.` - Returning to a time slightly after the time they left is just a default from the shell, not a hard requirement.  Martin travels back into his own past and into his own future and has even interacted with himself at several points in the series.

Answer (score 1):

Once Martin has full shell access his upgrades make him basically impervious from all harm except starving, and he could teleport away at a moments notice.

Returning to his home, even close to the time of the raid really doesn't present any serious danger to a person that is more or less immortal and can teleport away to another time and/or place at a whim.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but they took his phone before and he can't use magic without his staff or wand. Still +1 for you.

Comment: Another point.  Wizards do have the ability to setup proximity alerts in the shell and execute macros if someone enters a space.  I am not sure if, or which wizards have done this in original timeline homes but many have macros setup in their new homes.

Answer (score 1):

His cell phone app is the main reason why Martin keeps going back to his parent's home. He designed it with limited functions so all it can do is take him back to nearly the second after his departure. Once he has access to the Shell he doesn't have to use his phone anymore. So he could transport to any time or place he wished.

> "There was a button to take him back to wherever and whenever he was when he last time traveled. A temporal undo button, if you like. Handy for if he found himself someplace he didn't want to be."
>   -Off To Be The Wizard Page 26
>
> "Martin flipped the lid of the box open. The smartphone's screen glowed invitingly. He pulled up the app and looked at the options. He could go back to his own time, and be arrested like a civilized person. *No thanks.* He could teleport himself away and watch from a distance as his friends go beaten to death. *Not much better.* That left one option...."
>   -Off To Be The Wizard Page 333